# Selecting certain checkboxes

Tags: html

Is there a way select certain checkboxes in a list of multiple checkboxes? For instance I have a list of 50 companies. Some in the East and some in the West. I want to build a link that says "Select West" and it will only select the West ones. Select East, and it will only select the east ones. I'm new to html please dont bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little sample for you:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function check()
{
    document.myform.box.checked = true;
}

function uncheck()
{
    document.myform.box.checked = false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform">
<input type="checkbox" name="box">
<a href="javascript:check()">Check</a>
<a href="javascript:uncheck()">Uncheck</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in plain html, but you can use javascript and do the trick